# 64bit MacOs After succesfully installing Pygame: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, macos, pygame

Python noob here. I've been trying to install pygame and pandas for a few hours now. Even with Conda I did not succeed. I have Python 3.8.5 installed.

I eventually tried through the terminal with these commands:

```
python -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

and

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

(this was a total guess by the way, but apparently it did something)

Results were succesfull:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygame==2.0.0.dev6 in /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.0.0.dev6)
```

and

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.19.2 pandas-1.1.2 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1
```

But, when I try to import either modules, I still get errors. Any ideas?

```
import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

```
import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Do I need to move the modules to the script folder or something? Or what do I even move? Thanks!

Comment: Check that you have **path for scripts**  in your environment variable.

Comment: It's not good to mix pip with conda if you can avoid it. I would suggest creating a new conda environment, and installing the packages you need for it, through conda without using pip.

Comment: @matt this is what i got back:certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
conda==4.8.3
conda-package-handling==1.7.0+0.g7c4a471.dirty
cryptography==2.9.2
idna==2.9
numpy==1.19.2
pandas==1.1.2
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser==2.20
pygame==2.0.0.dev6
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
ruamel-yaml==0.15.87
six==1.15.0
tqdm==4.46.0
urllib3==1.25.8

Comment: @vishal sorry.. I'm a real noob.. i wish i knew what you meant.. do you maybe have a useful link?

Comment: I wrote "import pygame" in the IDLE file in the Python 3.8 folder and in the Visual Studio Code interpreter, both resulting in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame"

Comment: What is an idle file? From the same terminal you typed 'python -m pip freeze` and it showed you pygame, type `python` to enter a python shell. Then type `import pygame` if that doesn't work, then it sounds like your environment is broken.

Comment: ah ok, I got you, sorry for testing your patience :-) >>> import pandas as pd
>>> print(pd.__version__)
1.1.2 and >>> import pygame
pygame 2.0.0.dev6 (SDL 2.0.10, python 3.8.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

Comment: Right on, so it sounds like *that* environment works great. What are you doing that causes you get get the error?

Comment: Yes, conda creates environments with 'isolated' pythons so you can install packages in a 'safe' way. Pip is another tool for that. What you need to do is run the python in the correct conda environment.

Comment: @matt I really don't know.. this is wat I literally write in VS: import sys

import pygame and this is the error I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Comment: @matt first off, thanks for bearing with me dude. I'm trying to learn something after 40 hahaha. Anyway.. how do I know if Python is running in the correct conda environment? How do I change that?

Comment: @OsmanPolat right, because **that python environment** does not have pygame installed. Where did you type "import pygame" and it worked? The place the place that it worked type 'which python' and it should show you the location of the python that has pygame installed. Try the same thing from the VS console and it *probably* points to a different python.

Comment: You can change conda environments by using "conda activate 'env name'" I don't know enough about VS code though to say for certain. You might need to edit your question and include a vs code tag.

Comment: @matt ok. I've got it. It was succesfull in the Mac Terminal. The 'which python' command got me the correct path of the environment. As you said I needed to change the environment for VS. Now I have a whole bunch of different errors, but at least none where it can't find the module hahaha Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Got it thanks to @matt.. after succesfully installing pygame, find the environment in which pygame is installed by entering 'which python'.

In my case it returned:

/opt/miniconda3/bin/python

Now I needed to make sure the VS console was pointing at the same environment, by checking which python interpreter it was using and selecting the correct one. More info:

[how to check and change environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=To%20select%20a%20specific%20environment,or%20library%20versions%20as%20needed.)